# Can't connect my Samsung Galaxy S8 phone (Android Orio) to Linux (16.04 64 bit)

Tags: 16.04, android, mtp

I can't connect my Samsung Galaxy S8 phone (Android Orio) to Linux (16.04 64 bit).
I have selected Use USB To > Transfer Files mode.
I have tried enabling Developer Options, and USB Debugging. And MTP has been selected under USB configuration.

Then I tried with mtpfs in linux and it gives below ERROR while connecting to the S8.

```
$ sudo mtpfs -o allow_other ~/mnt
Listing raw device(s)
Device 0 (VID=xxxx and PID=xxxx) is a Samsung Galaxy models (MTP).
   Found 1 device(s):
   Samsung: Galaxy models (MTP) (xxxx:xxxx) @ bus x, dev xx
Attempting to connect device
LIBMTP ERROR: couldnt parse extension samsung.com/devicestatus:0
```

Can anyone share an idea on this?

Comment: I also can't connect Galaxy S8 to Ubuntu 18.04 - did you already find a solution?